# CSS3 transition max-height : 0 to max-height : 99999px

Tags: css, css-transitions

Hello

I am trying to make a according tabs with pure css3 , I know that transition doesn't work with `height : 0` to `height : auto` so im trying with `max-height : 0` to `max-height : 99999px`  . but I dont know why isn't work.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TgEK7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [one](http://jsfiddle.net/aloisdg/TgEK7/1/).

You have to target a property. If you use the word `all`, you target all properties. [Read about it on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions).

```
div {
    transition: <property> <duration> <timing-function> <delay>;
}
```

Example :

```
.ac-container article {
  -webkit-transition: 5s all;
  -moz-transition: 5s  all;
  -o-transition: 5s all;
  -ms-transition: 5s all;
  transition: 5s all;
}
```

Another error, you forget a `;` at :

```
.ac-container input:checked ~ article{
    max-height:999999px !important /* ; */
}
```

last thing,

If you use a big value (like `999999px`) and a small transition (like `0.5s`), the transition could work but you could not see it.

By the way, you dont need the keyword `!important`here.